# I failed when i trying to post my method from console app. My datas come 0 or null. What is my mistake?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I failed when i trying to post my method from console app. My datas always come 0 or null. I'm sharing my codes and error screenshot.

My Console App:

```
using MSE.DTO.DTOs.WorkStation;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

var random = new Random();

var data = new WorkStationRandomValueDTO
{
    WorkStationId = random.Next(1, 100),
    Temperature = (decimal)Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 100, 2),
    Pressure = (decimal)Math.Round(random.NextDouble() * 2000, 2),
    Status = random.Next(0, 1) == 1
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5002/WorkStationRandom/Post", content).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data saved successfully!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to save data: " + response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

My Mvc Api Controller Code :

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MSE.DataAccess.Context;
using MSE.DTO.DTOs.WorkStation;
using MSE.Entity.Entities.Concrete;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Web.Http;
using FromBodyAttribute = System.Web.Http.FromBodyAttribute;
using HttpGetAttribute = System.Web.Http.HttpGetAttribute;
using HttpPostAttribute = System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute;
using RouteAttribute = System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute;

namespace MSE.Web.Controllers
{
    public class WorkStationRandomController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public WorkStationRandomController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(WorkStationRandomValueDTO data)
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                var workStation = _mapper.Map<WorkStation>(data);
                _dbContext.WorkStations.Add(workStation);
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();

                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Data cannot be null.");
            }
        }
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "ok";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the picture of my error. My datas always come like this.

[My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Njl.png)

I'm trying to post data from using a console application but my datas come their default values (0 or null).

Comment: Please use 
"var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);"
It might seeding the new value

Comment: Why is this tagged with ASP.NET Core? `ApiController` AFAIK is part of the "classic" ASP.NET.  And `System.Web.Http.HttpGet` attibute too.

Comment: change the random value not working unfortunately.

Comment: Try `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    }
});` in the sending code.

Comment: I tried it but it's not working too.

Answer (score 1):

In your Controller on the post add [FromBody] attribute to your data variable in the declaration.

It chould also be that the serialization that MVC is trying to do from the posted data into your WorkStationRandomValueDTO is failing. If you change it to be a string and do the serialization yourself in code after perhaps you can catch the error.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(string data)
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
               var workStationRandonValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkStationRandomValueDTO>(data);
```

Comment: [FromBody] is not a right answer for me. I tried it but it's not working. Can you explain your second comment i mean about serialization thing. How can i do that? Can you give me example code part please?

Comment: Updated the answer with code example of how to change to a string as input and do the serialization yourself.

Answer (score 1):

your `Post` method is missing the `[FromBody]` attribute.

Adjust the code as below

```
[HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] WorkStationRandomValueDTO data)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            var workStation = _mapper.Map<WorkStation>(data);
            _dbContext.WorkStations.Add(workStation);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest("Data cannot be null.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your replace but it's not working. I tried it before i share the post and now but it's not working. I think my problem about serialization.

Comment: You can make use of the `PostAsJsonAsync()` from your console app

Comment: I tried it but it's not working thanzeel.